# Create new sequentially named variables and fill with mean of level

Tags: r, mean, quantile

Warning: Multi-part question!

I realize parts of this have been answered elsewhere but am struggling to bring them together in a nice parsimonious bit of code....

I have a data frame with a number (24) of numeric columns of interest. For each column, I want to create a new variable in the same data frame (named sensibly) in which the values correspond to the mean of the sex-specific decile for that variable (sex is in a different column, coded 0/1).

New column names from an original column called 'WBC' would be, for example: 'WBC_meandec_women', and 'WBC_meandeac_men'.

I've tried various bits of code to first create new variables, then assign values related to the decile but none work well and can't figure out how to put it together.  I just know there is a clever way to put all parts into the same code chunk, I'm just not fluent enough in R to get there...

```
dummydata <- data.frame(id=c(1:100),sex=rep(c(1,0),WBC=rnorm(100),RBC=rnorm(100))
```

Trying to achieve:

```
goaldata <-        data.frame(id=c(1:100),sex=rep(c(1,0),50),WBC=rnorm(100),RBC=rnorm(100),WBC_decmean_women=rep(NA,length(dummydata)),WBC_decmean_men=rep(NA,length(dummydata)),RBC_decmean_women=rep(NA,length(dummydata)),RBC_decmean_men=rep(NA,length(dummydata)))
```

...but obviously with the correct values instead of NAs, and for a list of about 24 original variables.

Any help greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on if I understood you right, I'll propose this giant ball of duct tape...

```
# fake data
dummydata <- data.frame(id=c(1:100),sex=rep(c(1,0),50),WBC=rnorm(100),RBC=rnorm(100))

# a function to calculate decile means
decilemean <- function(x) {
  xrank <- rank(x)
  xdec <- floor((xrank-1)/length(x)*10)+1
  decmeans <- as.numeric(tapply(x,xdec,mean))
  xdecmeans <- decmeans[xdec]
  return(xdecmeans)
}

# looping thru your data columns and making new columns
newcol <- 5          # the first new column to create
for(j in c(3,4)) {   # all of your colums to decilemean-ify
  dummydata[,newcol] <- NA
  dummydata[dummydata$sex==0,newcol] <- decilemean(dummydata[dummydata$sex==0,j])
  names(dummydata)[newcol] <- paste0(names(dummydata)[j],"_decmean_women")
  dummydata[,newcol+1] <- NA
  dummydata[dummydata$sex==1,newcol+1] <- decilemean(dummydata[dummydata$sex==1,j])
  names(dummydata)[newcol+1] <- paste0(names(dummydata)[j],"_decmean_men")
  newcol <- newcol+2
}
```

I'd recommend testing it though ;)

Comment: Super Matt, that seems to work!  Lovely and small too, thanks ever so much!